# Extract a substring from a string in shell script

Tags: regex, shell

```
$sea = xyz-ajay-no-siddhart-ubidone-fdh-DMJK.UK.1.0-32133-Z-1.tgz
```

and i want to extract only DMJK.UK.1.0-32133-Z-1 that is 1st occurenceand and search string will start as DMJK.

```
$sea = anything-anything.xyz-ajay-no-siddhart-ubidone-fdh-DMJK.UK.1.0-32133-Z-1.tgz matchessadds.dsdsds.21212.anything-anything
```

or
$sea = anything-anything.xyz-ajay-no-siddhart-ubidone-fdh-DMJK.UK.1.0-32133-Z-1.tar.bz2 matchessadds.dsdsds.21212.anything-anything

need to extract start from DMJK and before either ".tgz" or ".tar" or "tar.bz2",

o/p should be DMJK.UK.1.0-32133-Z-1 in the above case.

main String can be anything that include the format

"anything.anything-DMJK.XXX.[]0-9].[0-9].[0-9]-3213309-[A-Z]-[0-9].tar.tgz anything-anything "

change on fly, o/p could be DMJK.XXX.1.3.0-3213309-Z-13

I tried but its not working:

```
echo $sea | sed 's#.*(DMJK.*).t*#\1#g'
```

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways to do this, but you can fix your current solution with:

```
sed -E 's#.*(DMJK.*)\.(tgz|tar.bz2|tar)#\1#g'
```

( well, sort of.  This will perhaps not work as desired on a string with .tar.bz5.  It's not entirely clear what you want to do in that case, though.)

Comment: why o/p is coming link 
DMJK.UK.1.0-32133-Z-1 matches

Comment: o/p is coming link that because matches re as designed.  (?)  Using -E tells sed to used extended regular expressions, so the pattern matches DMJK followed by antyhing (that is the first group) followed by any of "tgz", "tar.bz2", or "tar".  (note that "tarxbz2" also matches, since the '.' is a meta-character, but that entire field is redundant anyway since it matches the 'tar')